# What is the type of the list being returned?

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following piece of code:

```
class Test{
  static <T> List<T> lstOf(T ...values){
      List<T> lst = new ArrayList<T>(values.length);
      for ( T val : values)
          lst.add(val);
      return lst;
  }

    static class Obj<T>{
        T value;
        public Obj(T val){
            this.value = val;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Obj<Integer> intVal = new Obj<Integer>(22);
        Obj<Long> longVal = new Obj<Long>(22L);
        List<Obj<? extends Number>> lst = lstOf(intVal, longVal);
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that "lst" is of type

```
java.util.List<Test.Obj<? extends java.lang.Number&java.lang.Comparable<? extends java.lang.Number&java.lang.Comparable<?>>>>
```

What is the type of the list object returned by lstOf method? How do I successfully assign a type to the returned value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inferred type is `List<Test.Obj<? extends Number & Comparable<? extends Number & Comparable<?>>>>` as the message indicates. This is because Java is picking the most specific type that is common to the arguments it is given (both have type arguments that are `Number`s that implement `Comparable`). To make it just use the type you're interested in, `Obj<? extends Number>`, call it as:

```
List<Obj<? extends Number>> lst = Test.<Obj<? extends Number>>lstOf(intVal, longVal);
```

Comment: Thanks! that works. but compiling with -Xlint still warns me of unchecked generic array creation -- I guess it has to do with the varargs lstOf method.

Comment: @Ajay: Yes, generic types and varargs don't play nice together. In Java 7, you'll be able to suppress that warning at the declaration of `lstOf` so that callers won't get it.

Comment: Cool. fingers crossed for JDK 7

Answer (score 2):

ColinD has the detailed answer, but I would suggest instead specifying `lst`:

```
List<? extends Obj<? extends Number>> lst = lstOf(intVal, longVal);
```

Comment: Limitation: In this solution, one can't append anything other than `null` to `lst`.

Comment: Yeah, like @meriton says, this imposes additional restrictions on the list that aren't necessary.

Comment: Thanks. your solutions work for me as well(since I don't need to modify the list returned by lstOf() method)

Answer (score 0):

It is a type of the parameter you're passing to the method.

If you call `lstOf(String ... strs)` then the result is `List<String>`.